# wysiwyg module and imce missing upload button

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I am attaching an image....i have wysiwyg module with cke library and also imce module and imce bridge module.

When I click browse to upload images, i get a nonfunctioning screen....It does not work at all. no upload buttons. And there are jquery errors in developer. I updated jquery update to version 3 but still nothing.

I have selected 1,7 version jquery for administration, 1.10. default drupal jquery...nothing works....[image]

Comment: Sometime your custom jquery code is getting triggered there for particular buttons. If you have written any jquery or css code for ur website. Please confirm for list tag display:none property is there or what.